# Bash: Time between actions?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

How would I make a bash script to tell me the time it takes between a message returned and a user pressing any key after that? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "button" ?

Comment: I might suggest that Bash is not really the best language to choose for event-handling...

Comment: Bash is the only thing I have time to use. I don't know anything else and I have a close deadline. And by button, I mean key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic implementation for the enter key and giving time in seconds:

```
t0=`date +%s`
echo Press enter...
read
t1=`date +%s`

echo Elapsed: $[$t1-$t0]
```

replacing `%s` with `%s%N` would measure nanoseconds. (`%N` gives nanoseconds padded with zeroes)

On some platforms, this may work to catch the "any key":

```
stty cbreak
t0=`date +%s%N`
echo Press any key...
dd bs=1 count=1 of=/dev/null 2>/dev/null
t1=`date +%s%N`

echo Elapsed: $[($t1-$t0)/1000000] microseconds
```

Comment: Wow. That was simple. I feel like I should have know that.